# serving maintenance page on website, will affect google indexing?

Tags: html, google-index

I don't think this is an issue but my partner is worried that by only serving a maintenance page for 24 hours (as we need to restore the database as was accidently deleted) that it could have a negative affect on our Google index/rating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would follow Google’s [recommendations on blacking out your website to protest SOPA](https://plus.google.com/115984868678744352358/posts/Gas8vjZ5fmB). Specifically:

1. Return a `503 Service Unavailable` status code for pages which are unavailable.
2. Make sure that `robots.txt` does not return a 503 status code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the best way to deal with this is throwing an error code 503 Service Unavailable and use a custom error document to style it more friendly.

Answer (score 1):

to be sure that there are no problems, you should serve your page using the 503 Service Temporarily Unavailable status. Retry-After can also be set, but i am not sure if the google crawlers care about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude it from crawlers like Google's by using a robots.txt  file in the root of the site for that 24 hour period.